# check if any the selection boxes are no selected in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a web app in `HTML`.
There are several selection boxes with the same name.
I want to check if any of them are not selected.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

                                                <select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard" >
                                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                                <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
                                                <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
                                            </select>

                                                <select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard" >
                                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                                <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
                                                <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
                                            </select>
...
                                                <select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard" >
                                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                                <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
                                                <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
                                            </select>
```

I have tried:

```
<script>

            if ($('[id="keep_discard"]').text() == '--Select--')
            {

               alert("some selection box not selected");
            }
</script>
```

And

```
 <script>         if ($('[name="keep_discard"]').text() == '--Select--')
            {

               alert("some selection box not selected");
            }
</script>
```

But both failed to do the verification.
How could I check if any of the selection box not selected?

Comment: You can't have the same `id` attribute more than once in the page. anyway.. this should work `$('[name="keep_discard"]').filter(s => s.value).length`

Comment: not working using .filter(s => s.value).length, always 0 even I select all the boxes

Comment: The ID cannot be repeated as you do here. When is the check to be performed and how is it triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the select tags have same id and name, you can select the nodes with `$('select')` this will give you the list of `select` nodes. Check the value of each of them.

Use either `$('select').map` or `$('select').each`

```js
function checkSelect() {
  let isEmpty = false;
  $('select').map((index, node) => {
    if (node.value === '') {
      isEmpty = true
      console.log(`node ${index+1} is empty`);
    }
  })
  if (isEmpty === false) {
    console.log('All inputs are filled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<button onclick="checkSelect()">Check Select</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, in some case my selection boxes may not be 3(the number of the selection boxes is not fixed), how could I check then?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through of all select box and check the value

```js
function checkSelect() {
let AllisEmpty = true;
  $('[name="keep_discard"]').each(function(t,x){
  //console.log(x);
    if(x.value)
      AllisEmpty = false;
  });

  console.log(AllisEmpty)
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<button onclick="checkSelect()">Check Select</button>
```

Comment: @Django Has your problem been solved? you just need the Boolean flag and go through all of your select box and if one of them has value set the flag false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` for select all select with name keep_discard then see if is empty or not the value and print it like:

```js
function checkSelect() {
  let counter = 0;
  $('select[name="keep_discard"]').each((index, el) => {
    if ($(el)[0].value === '') {
      counter++;
      console.log(index + ' select are empty');
    }
  });
  if (counter === 0) {
    console.log('All are seleced');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<select name="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>

<select name="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<select name="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
<button onclick="checkSelect()">Check Select</button>
```

Comment: how to return to the caller if some selection box are ''? I tried adding return after console.log(index + ' select are empty'); but it could not stop the function

Comment: I don't understand "how to return to the caller". what you mean?

Comment: I added return false; after console.log(index + ' select are empty'); , but could not return

Comment: Why you need to return false?

Comment: because if user make all the selection, I would submit to backend, and if user did not, I should do nothing

Comment: Just use event.preventDefault(); at start submit then form.submit(); if all is ok

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.each` and run a ***.change*** event on the selectors to check the value of the event target.

```js
$('[name="keep_discard"]').each(function(){
  let error = null;
  $(this).change(function(e){
    if(e.target.value === ""){
      error = alert('Please select an option')
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'
    }else{
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ddd'
    }
  })
  return error
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>

<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
...
<select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the duplicate IDs from these select menus.
A simple `querySelectorAll` in vanilla js will allow you to assign an event handler to each `select` which can easily test for the `selectedIndex` property - any that have 0 as the `selectedIndex` are to be flagged in some manner.

```js
let col=document.querySelectorAll('select[name="keep_discard"]');
col.forEach( sel=>sel.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  col.forEach( sel=>{
    sel.classList.remove('error');
    if( sel.options.selectedIndex==0 )sel.classList.add('error')
  })
}))
```

```css
.error{border:2px solid red;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25)}
```

```html
<select name="keep_discard">
  <option>--Select--
  <option value="Keep">Keep
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove
</select>

<select name="keep_discard">
  <option>--Select--
  <option value="Keep">Keep
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove
</select>

<select name="keep_discard">
  <option>--Select--
  <option value="Keep">Keep
  <option value="Remove" selected="selected">Remove
</select>
```